# Normal abelian subgroups of a quotient group of the centralizer of the Fitting subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

This is exercise $1.D.19$ of Isaacs' "Finite Group Theory". It goes:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $F = F(G)$ be its Fitting subgroup. Let $C = C_G(F) = \{x \in G \mid xf = fx, \forall f \in F\}$. Show that $C/(C \cap F)$ has no nontrivial normal abelian subgroups. **HINT**: $F(C) \lhd G$

---

I was able to translate the question into proving there is no subgroup $C\cap F \neq A$ of $G$ such that the following conditions hold:

- $A \lhd C$;
- $A' \subset C\cap F \subset A$

I.e, if $A$ is a subgroup satisfying both of them, then $A = C \cap F$. So all I have to do is take such a subgroup and show $A \subset F$. The problem is: I have *no* idea how to do that... I would have to prove that $A \lhd G$ and that $A$ is nilpotent, but I don't see how these are connected to the hypotheses (or the hint, for that matter)...

What is it that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Disclaimer**: Even though I have recently asked another question regarding this book, these are **not** homework assignments. I've been reading the book on my own and have no other source/colleague to talk to regarding the questions, especially those more specific, such as this one.

Comment: We have $C \cap F \le Z(A)$, so $A$ is  nilpotent, hence $A \le F(C) \le F(G)=F$. But $C \cap F \subset A$ implies $A \not\subseteq F$, contradiction. (You don't need to prove $A \lhd G$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Wow, thank you so much! I had completely missed $F \subset Z(A)$… Such a silly overlook!

Answer (score 0):

**General fact**. Suppose that $H\le G$ is an $A$-invariant subgroup, where $A\le Aut(G)$. Then $N_G(H)$ and $C_G(H)$ are $A$-invariant.

Thats how we use it. Centralizer of a normal subgroup is normal. It follows that
$$
   \overline{C}=CF/F\simeq C/C\cap F\unlhd G/F=\overline{G}.
$$

Now suppose that there is a normal abelian subgroup $H\unlhd \overline{C}$. Then $F(\overline{C})\ne 1$. Since Fitting subgroup is characteristic and characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is normal, we have $1\ne F(\overline{C})\unlhd F(\overline{G})$. A contradiction, since $F(\overline{G})=1$.

Comment: But we don't necessarily have $F(\bar{G})=1$.

Comment: Yes. You are right, I have a mistake